# Why does my variable (winning) not get reassigned when I try to reassign it?

Tags: python, if-statement, reassign

```
def winningcheck(board):

    winning == ''
    
    if board[1] == board[2] == board[3]: 
        
        print('The game has been won')
        
        winning == 'True'
        
    else:
        print('The game has not been won')
        

test = ['#', 'X ', 'X ', 'X ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

winningcheck(test)

print(winning)
```

I'm a beginner, but I expected the variable winning to be reassigned to 'true' when the 'if' condition was met. However, it just returns an empty string instead when I try to print the variable.

Comment: `winning == ''`? `winning == 'True'`?

Comment: And why do you use strings instead of boolean values?

Comment: Winning has a limited scope, as it's defined within the function only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did `winning==` instead of `winning='True'`, this was a condition and not an assignment.
Additionally you need to make winning a global variable as I've shown. otherwise the code outisde the function can't access it.

```py
winning = ''
def winningcheck(board):
    global winning
    if board[1] == board[2] == board[3]: 
        
        print('The game has been won')
        
        winning = 'True'
        
    else:
        print('The game has not been won')
        

test = ['#', 'X ', 'X ', 'X ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

winningcheck(test)

print(winning)
```

But you should use a boolean variable for `winning` instead of a string, as its more efficient and it serves the intended use for you.
So you would init `winning = False` and change with `winning = True`.

Comment: In your example you need to declare ```winning``` as a global variable inside your function as well. Otherwise you create a local ```winning``` variable inside ```winningcheck``` shadowing the global scope variable when assigning a new value

Comment: True, I'm used to c++ rather than python so i forgot :). Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

Comparison:

```
winning == 'True'
```

Assignment:

```
winning = True
```

Note the different number of "=".